# Difference between mini-jumbo and grand auditorium? Specifically, on the Washburn EA15ATB compared to Taylor's GA?

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar

According to [Guitar Center](https://www.guitarcenter.com/Washburn/Festival-EA15A-Spruce-Top-With-Flame-Maple-Veneer-Acoustic-Cutaway-Electric-Guitar-With-4-Band-EQ.gc), there doesn't *appear* to be any difference compared to [Taylor's standard of GA](https://www.taylorguitars.com/guitars/acoustic/features/shapes/grand-auditorium), but Taylor doesn't provide any more dimensions past the length, width, and depth.

Comment: Marketing. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Yeah I've kinda figured that out by now

Answer (score 2):

Both shapes are known to be one of the most versatile and common shapes. So, yes, generally speaking, it is not wrong to say there is no difference.

However, this is a subject that affects acoustics and ease of use of the guitar directly. In these kind of parameters, just by looking to specs, it is really hard to say if it will feel okay or not. Probably, you will be satisfied with both shapes/guitars. But I would strongly suggest that you go to a local music store and try it in real life.